# Xcode 7.1 (Bêta 1) / InterfaceBuilder for tvOS Crash

Tags: xcode, storyboard, interface-builder, tvos, apple-tv

I can't drag and drop any ViewController from UIObject library to my Stroyboard using XCode 7.1 (bêta 1).

Everytime I try to drag and drop a simple UIViewController (for example), XCode crash.

By the way, is there an option to reduce the size of the ViewController when disposed in the Storyboard ? When I zoom i can add controls, but not when i unzoom it.

EDIT : I have a MacBook Pro end-2014 with a 500Go SSD drive, 16Go RAM + intel core i5 ...

Comment: find any fix to this? Mine just started doing the same

Comment: It seems Xcode 7.1 Bêta 3 solved this problem although it was not announced in release notes.

Comment: Eh, had the issue on b3. Just reinstalled and that worked though